# Derby database path with whitespace

Tags: client-server, whitespace, derby

When using derby client driver, if there is white space in connection url, the connection get refused. Otherwise its ok.

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1888/c:/my database/db
```

reports

```
no database found
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple technique is to use the generated Windows short name instead of the long name.

Run 'DIR /X' in "C:\" to figure out the shortname of the "my database" directory, and then use that name for the folder instead of the name with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`c:/my database` is likely accessible by the shortcut  `c:/mydata~1`.

The shortcut is formed by taking the first 6 non-whitespace characters of the directory name/filename then appending `~1` as the seventh and eighth characters.  (If there was another `mydata~1`, then `~2` would be used.

This was used to get around the former 8 character limit for files and directories in MS-DOS.